# Fantasy Series in a cold climate with corrupted animals and people being famed for taking them down, LGB people referred to as Followers of Artemis

Tags: story-identification, novel

There's this book series I started back in 2014 that I can't remember the name of and would like to finish it now that I have the time.

The main details I can remember about the setting was it was in a very cold climate, there was a side male character who was royalty and also gay, and gay people in universe were referred to as followers of Artemis. The main character could've been a prince, or the son of a powerful Noble. I believe there was also a theme of corrupted animals and people getting great fame for taking one down, but this is a little fuzzy so I'm not so sure about the fame part. Also the main characters sister was chosen to be a part of a nunnery for the in universe major religion? The first book's cover was white as well I'm pretty sure, if that helps.

I remember also that there was one part in the book that the main character and I think the other guy who is gay were going somewhere and there was a frozen lake they had to cross, and the lake itself was at the bottom of a cliff, and in order to get down they went to a house on the cliff where some hardy old lady lived and she operated a lift to let people down to the lake.

Something else I remember, is the character who was gay had an amulet that marked him as a follower of Artemis, and this is what outed him to the main character, and that's when the whole followers of Artemis thing comes in, and I remembered thinking it was cool that the gay character was a follower of Artemis and used a bow. The main character definitely had a sword.

I also do not believe this was YA fantasy, pretty sure it was in the normal fantasy section in Barnes and Noble

I went to Barnes and Noble yesterday, and could not find the book. I also went through their online catalog and couldn't find it. So it's possible that B&N no longer carry it, if that helps